# How to get SubstringValues from Textbox

Tags: c#-4.0

```
len = int.Parse(tE1Clt.Text);

front=int.Prase(tE_Fstng.text);

string result = tE3_Series.Text.Substring(front, len);
tE1_Sub.Text = result.ToString();
```

I'm getting error

```
[index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: `length`]
```

Comment: my guess without seeing your inputs/values is that your len variable is greater than the length of your tE3_Series textbox. please post more information so we can verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if (TeInput.Text.Length > 1)
            {

```
            string Input = TeInput.Text, Store1 = string.Empty, store2 = string.Empty;
            int Start = 0, End = 0;
            Start = int.Parse(TeStart.Text);

            End = int.Parse(TeEnd.Text);
            string Output = TeOutput.Text;

            Store1 = Input.Remove(0, Start).Trim();
            store2 = Store1.Remove(Store1.Length-End).Trim();
            TeOutput.Text = store2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
            var str = "----takemeout----";
            var start = str.IndexOf('t'); // start index of first t
            var length = 9; // length of takemeout string
            var result = str.Substring(start, length);
```

Value or result will be "takemeout"